# Problems calling class function in another class function

Tags: php, function, class

I am trying to build my own little framework.
Now I am having problems calling class functions into another class function.

Users.php code

```
class User extends Connection{
public function __construct(Connection $conn, Log $log){
    parent::__construct($log);

    $this->conn = $conn;
}

public function generatePassword(){
    $length = 12;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $password = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    return $password;
}

public function generateToken(){
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    return $token;
}

public function checkUsername($prefix, $username){
    echo "test";
}

}

$user = new User($conn, $log);
$conn = new Connection($log);
```

connection.php code

```
<?php
class Connection{

private $log;
private $db;

public function __construct(Log $log){
    $this->log = $log;

    $this->createConnection();
}

public function createConnection(){
    $dataConnection = $this->getConnection();

    $host = $dataConnection['localhost'];
    $dbname = $dataConnection['dbname'];
    $user = $dataConnection['user'];
    $pass = $dataConnection['pass'];

    try{
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.'',$user,$pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->log->insertLog("installer","Trying to connect to database");
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->errorHandling($e->getCode());
    }
}

public function errorHandling($error){
    switch ($error){
        case 2002:
            $this->log->insertLog("installer","Installer error code 2002: Host unknown");
            return ('Host unkown');
            break;
        case 1049:
            $this->log->insertLog("installer","Installer error code 1049: Database does not exist");
            return ('Database does not exist');
            break;
        case 1045:
            $this->log->insertLog("installer","Installer error code 1045: Could not connect to database");
            return ('Could nog connect to database');
            break;
    }
}

public function getConnection(){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("config/config.xml");

    $dataConnection = array();
    $dataConnection['localhost'] = $xml->host;
    $dataConnection['dbname'] = $xml->dbname;
    $dataConnection['user'] = $xml->user;
    $dataConnection['pass'] = $xml->pass;

    return $dataConnection;
}

public function query($sql){
    try {
        $this->db->exec($sql);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->errorHandling($e->getCode());
    }
}

public function select($sql){
    try{
        $result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->errorHandling($e->getCode());
    }
}
}

$conn = new Connection($log);
$log = new Log();
```

Log.php code

```
<?php
class Log{

public function createLog($file){
    $date = date("dmY");
    $location = 'var/log/'.$file.'-'.$date.'.log';
    if (!file_exists($location)){
        $file = fopen($location, 'w');
        $message = "/** LOG FILE CREATED **/\n";
        file_put_contents($location,$message, FILE_APPEND);
        fclose($file);
    }
    return $location;
}

public function insertLog($file,$message){
    $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", time());
    $location = $this->createLog($file);
    $message = $date." - ".$message."\n";
    file_put_contents($location, $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
}

$log = new Log();
```

Now when I am trying to call the function checkUsername on user.php (will be used to check if the username already exists in db) I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: log in
>   /opt/www/decocka2/web/www.anthonydecock.be/core/conn/connection.php on
>   line 77
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Connection::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Log, null given, called in
>   /opt/www/decocka2/web/www.anthonydecock.be/core/conn/connection.php on
>   line 77 and defined in
>   /opt/www/decocka2/web/www.anthonydecock.be/core/conn/connection.php on
>   line 7

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the connection and the log object before the user object.